# Неизвестная ошибка в Intelij IDEA на языке JAVA

Tags: java, intelij

Начал писать элементарный цикл и возникла непонятная ошибка без причин. Перезагружал интегрированную среду и пк. Не помогло. Почему есть ошибка без причин? Что делать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

первая ошибка - показать код картинкой.

вторая ошибка - не читали документацию, иначе бы написали где то так

```
for (int count = 2; count <= 100; count++) {
}
```

обратите внимания, что там точка с запятой, а не просто запятая.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не сказал, что неизвестная ошибка, т.к. ниже ясно написано следующее:

```
';' expected
```

Она возникает оттого, что все выражения внутри скобок в `for` нужно разделять **точками с запятой, а не запятыми** — один из материалов про это написан [здесь](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/for-v-java). Просто напишите

```java
for (count = 2; count <= 100; count++) {
}
```

P.S. Третье выражение лучше переписать в `count++` — правила языка не запрещают так делать